# Setting number of columns in output window with c++

Tags: visual-c++

I have created a Fibonacci program that runs correctly. However I can not figure out how to format the output window the way the problem would like. The rows and spacing are correct but the program should display 6 columns, as it is now the program outputs nine with the ninth cut off. Am I doing something wrong or missing something? I am using the Visual Studio C++ compiler.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void main ()
{
int FirstNum = 1;
int SecondNum = 0;
int Count = 1;
int Answer;

do
{

    Answer = FirstNum + SecondNum;
    FirstNum = SecondNum;
    SecondNum = Answer;

cout << FirstNum << setw (10);

Count++;

} while (Count < 40);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will generated only 6 columns.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
int FirstNum = 1;
int SecondNum = 0;
int Count = 1;
int Answer;
do
{
Answer = FirstNum + SecondNum;
FirstNum = SecondNum;
SecondNum = Answer;
cout << setw (10)<< FirstNum ;
Count++;
if(Count%6==0)
cout<<endl;
} while (Count < 40);
return 0;
}
```